# Hints needed on basic proof involving functions and relations.

Tags: functions, relations

Let $F = \{f\mid f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R\}$, and define a relation $S$ on $F$ as follows:
$S = \{(f,g) ∈ F \times F \mid \exists h \in F :f = h\circ g\}$.
Let $f$, $g$ and $h$ be the functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ defined by the formulas
$f(x) = x^2 + 1$, $g(x) = x^3 + 1$, and $h(x) = x^4 + 1$. Prove that $h\,S\,f$,
but that it is not the case that $g\, S\, f$.

By letting $j(x) = x^2 - 2x + 2$, then $h = j \circ f$, thus $h\, S\,f$.

I've been struggling to show that it is **not** the case that $g\,S\,f$. In specific, I need to show that $g$ is not equal to $j \circ f$, for arbitrary $j \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this could help: If $g=h\circ f$ and $f(x)=f(y)$ for some $x$, $y$, what can you say about values of $g$ at $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Since it is only your second post here and the question sounds a little like a homework, I think I should mention this: [How to ask a homework question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)

Comment: g(x)=h(f(x))=h(f(y))=g(y). If $x \neq y$, then this is a contradiction, since g is injective. Thus, g $\neq$ h∘f.

Comment: Seems ok to me. You might as well post your comment as an answer; perhaps adding more details. It's ok to answer your own question: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ BTW a related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28123/if-gfx-is-one-to-one-injective-show-fx-is-also-one-to-one-given-that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $j:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary.
Let $a=1, b=-1$, so $j(f(a))=j(f(b))$, thus $j ∘ f$ is not injective. Since, $g$ is injective, then $g \neq j ∘ f$.